# Tableau ERROR: column reference "datasource" is ambiguous; Error while executing the query Unable to create extract

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a tde file from a live data source. I am connecting to multiple materialized views in postgres so the data source is a custom sql query. Everything in the workbook runs fine while live but when I try to extract the data, I receive the error:

`ERROR: column reference "datasource" is ambiguous; Error while executing the query
Unable to create extract`

I do have multiple tables with the same field name so I aliased each of the fields accordingly in my custom query. It seems that when Tableau creates their query for extract, the aliasing isn't recognized. Any help is very appreciated.

```
SELECT
 i.trx_line_id
,i.datasource
,ie.category_type
,ss.trx_line_id
,ss.datasource
,pl.pl_cd


FROM   invoice i

LEFT   JOIN sales_structure ss ON i.trx_line_id = ss.trx_line_id
LEFT   JOIN invoice_ext ie ON i.trx_line_id = ie.trx_line_id
LEFT   JOIN product_level pl ON i.pl_cd = pl.pl_cd

WHERE  ss.sales_team_rpt IN ('a','b')
```

Comment: Does `\`TableName\`.\`field\`` work?

Comment: When I replace the alias with TableName I recieve this error: `ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "TableName"; Error while executing the query` when I try to exit the custom query.

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: Your query does not show a field named 'field'. Did you alter the error message or is this the correct query?

Comment: I altered it. corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning to Tableau a set of data where fields (`datasource` and `trx_line_id`) have the same name. A simple fix would be to alias those fields:

```
SELECT
    i.trx_line_id AS invoice_line_id, -- Aliased
    i.datasource AS invoice_datasource, -- Aliased
    ie.category_type,
    ss.trx_line_id AS sales_structure_line_id, -- Aliased
    ss.datasource AS sales_structure_datasource, -- Aliased
    pl.pl_cd
FROM
    invoice i
LEFT JOIN
    sales_structure ss ON i.trx_line_id = ss.trx_line_id
LEFT JOIN
    invoice_ext ie ON i.trx_line_id = ie.trx_line_id
LEFT JOIN
    product_level pl ON i.pl_cd = pl.pl_cd
WHERE
    ss.sales_team_rpt IN ('a','b');
```

Comment: I had aliased the tables but didn't think about the individual fields. Thanks!

Comment: This of course means it's not possible to use SELECT * -- I was stumped for ages, thanks for the help!